# if P=NP then $L\leq L'$ for all languages

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

How can I prove that if P=NP then for each non-trivial language $L,L'\in NP$ there exists a polynomial reduction $L\leq L'$?

Comment: I don't really know much about complexity but this sounds wrong to me. Take L to be a polynomial recognizable language and take L' to be an RE-hard language. I don't think, even if P=NP, that there is a polytime reduction from L' to L.

Comment: The correct version adds the requirement that $L,L'$ belong to $\mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: Think: what can a polynomial-time reduction do? Also, you have to require that $L'\notin \{\Sigma^*,\emptyset\}$, otherwise this is false.

Comment: You can define a reduction to take every x that belongs to L to y that belongs to L' and every x' that does not belong to L to y' that does not belong to L'? @Shaull

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You should first fix x' and y', of course, otherwise the reduction might not be polynomial (you can't compute them mid-reduction).

Comment: This is pretty much by definition.